# Python | How to make a program that calculates strings

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to create a Python script using pandas that can import a .txt file and 
calculate the average of each subject

I'm trying to turn this "file.txt":

```
code name subject1 subject2 subject3
1234 Ali 6 0 8
1235 Carl 4 7 7
1236 Jason 3 5 0
```

and turn in intro this:

```
subject1 average is: 4.3
subject2 average is: 6
subject3 average is: 7.5
```

- subject1 is calculated like this: (6 + 4 + 3) / 3,
- subject2 is calculated like this: (7 + 5) / 2 <-- because one person has a 0
  means he/she didn't anticipate so their 0 does't add and counts
  toward the average
- subject3 is calculated like this: (8 + 7) / 2 <-- Like above

  I'm also trying to figure out a way for the script to be flexible and have the ability to add more subjects and more people (so 3 instead of 5)

This is my code until now:

```
# read input file
df = pd.read_csv('file.txt')

# calculate mean, ignoring 0 values
df['mean'] = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(float).replace(0, np.nan).mean(1)

# iterate rows and print results
for name, mean in df.set_index('name')['mean'].items():
    print(f'{name} has average of {mean:.2f}')
```

- It calculates the average of each person (horizontally)
- but I can't figure out a way to do it vertically for each subject.

thanks for the help guys ^_^

Comment: What kind of help do you expect? Do you want us to write code for you? If so, we don't do that: we only help with specific issues in concrete code. Otherwise, please post the code you've written to solve this and explain what the issue is.

Comment: @ForceBru, I added more information, I already have some code I hope it help thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument `1` that you provide to `pd.Series.mean` is the axis along which the mean is calculated; the default is columns, so you are explicitly telling it to calculate the row-wise mean. Remove that argument and you should be good.

```
In [155]: df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(float).replace(0, np.nan).mean()
Out[155]:
subject1    4.333333
subject2    6.000000
subject3    7.500000
```

Comment: Is it possible to both calculate the horizontal and vertical to print both calculations?

Comment: Well, that's what you're doing. If you let `df_nan = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(float).replace(0, np.nan)`, then you could print `df_nan.mean()` first, then `df_nan.mean(1)` afterwards.

Comment: Great, you're welcome. If you found the answer helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). Besides giving us mostly useless internet points, this helps to indicate which questions on StackOverflow are still in need of attention.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you good, you want to do this.

```
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv('data.csv',sep=' ')
    #You can change the range for number of subjects
    for i in range(1,4):
    #Print average for subject
    print(datos['subject'+str(i)].mean())
```